# JSON Data populates textViews incorrectly

Tags: java, android, json, youtube

I have 3 textViews I'm attempting to populate using JSON - I am able to get the data into the textViews but for some reason I get incorrect data (I'm attempting to use the values for name, content and published in the JSON response below.) I also noticed the same data is repeated over and over when I should have a list of unique comments. I'm not sure exactly what I've done wrong but any suggestions are appreciated.

### JAVA:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.player);
        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        String uploader = getIntent().getStringExtra("uploader");
        String viewCount = getIntent().getStringExtra("viewCount");
        TextView titleTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTv);
        TextView uploaderTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.uploaderTv);
        TextView viewCountTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.viewCountTv);

        titleTv.setText(title);
        uploaderTv.setText("by" + uploader + " |");
        viewCountTv.setText(viewCount + " views");
        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(Player.this, list);
        lv.setAdapter(cus);

        Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask task = new GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(
                handler, viewCount);

        task.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
            YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onInitializationFailure()",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider,
            YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
        if (!wasRestored) {
            String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");
            player.loadVideo(video_id);
        }
    }

    public final class GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask extends
            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        public static final String LIBRARY = "CommentsLibrary";
        private final Handler replyTo;
        private final String username;
        String video_id = getIntent().getStringExtra("id");

        public GetYouTubeUserCommentsTask(Handler replyTo, String username) {
            this.replyTo = replyTo;
            this.username = username;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(
                        "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
                                + video_id
                                + "/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true");

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

                String jsonString = StreamUtils.convertToString(response
                        .getEntity().getContent());

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONObject("feed").getJSONArray(
                        "entry");

                List<Comments> comments = new ArrayList<Comments>();

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObject.optString("name", "defaultValue");
                    String content = jsonObject.optString("content",
                            "defaultValue");
                    String published = jsonObject.optString("published",
                            "defaultValue");
                    list.add(new CommentsLibrary(name, content, published));
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Feck", e);
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }

    }

    public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        LayoutInflater mInflater;
        ArrayList<CommentsLibrary> list;

        public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CommentsLibrary> list) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                        false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                holder.tv3 = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.tv1.setText(list.get(position).getName());
            holder.tv2.setText(list.get(position).getContent());
            holder.tv3.setText(list.get(position).getPublished());
            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView tv1, tv2, tv3;

        }
    }
}
```

### JSON RESPONSE:

```
{"encoding":"UTF-8","feed":{"logo":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.gstatic.com\/youtube\/img\/logo.png"},"link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments?v=2","rel":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#feed"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/batch?v=2","rel":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#batch"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments?alt=json&max-results=50&v=2","rel":"self"},{"type":"application\/atomsvc+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments?alt=atom-service&v=2","rel":"service"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments?alt=json&alt=json&start-token=Gq4ECqsECDISpgQACgAAAEQSAQAgAAgAEAIAgQALIAIAACFAAAAAAACQMCGAYQAkgASQACEAAgEAAAAQAHAAAQQAoQCYAIFGAEAIKgMgBAASASACAAgAAAABBAAKIAAAAJgMIAjARIAAAAUAAAAIAhCDMggSCAQAAAIIAAQEiAAgBAAQQEIIEAAEAACBgShAAiAAAAgAAAIAgQAgAYXEAiMAAgACAAAQAACAQAAQACCAAQQASAQQAAgAAEREAAAAAYABQSAAAABAQAAAhAAKBBAgQAAAACIAAAIECBMCgQBMAAACEEAQAIBAAIQgAIgAJgAAEJgAAgBAABIBCIAAAAgEASABAAIAAAAiAgCAgAAIABgEACEEAAgIAAgAQAAAAAACAAVAWIAQkAiBwAAAJAASACgCAAAECEASBIwwAEAAQhBAADAAAAAAAABAABAxYAACACAhAAEEgAAgQAABAABAARAgISAAAgAAAgYCEAAAYjAAIEABGQEAAABAAAAUAAAAggAAIAELACAJEIAAAABAEEAAg4AEUgABAAggShAADAABASADAAAAACgZRACAAAAEAAAIAAoQCHALIgEAAAAKAAAAAC4AAABAQAAAAAQAQAAAAiAAAAAABBRABAABFEMAQAAEAAIIQABMhAQQAAAYgABCAAIgABAAAMACAAYYIAggABIEBACEoAAIEAEABAEAAAsIQEAAAAAgAAAEEAAAAKFAgAQECAgAASkARhARKJzIiNL4gLsCMJScl6aUtbsCOAFAAQ%3D%3D&max-results=50&v=2","rel":"next"}],"openSearch$totalResults":{"$t":664},"xmlns":"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/Atom","id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comments"},"author":[{"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/"},"name":{"$t":"YouTube"}}],"xmlns$openSearch":"http:\/\/a9.com\/-\/spec\/opensearch\/1.1\/","category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"xmlns$gd":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005","updated":{"$t":"2013-12-16T16:26:06.146Z"},"xmlns$yt":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007","gd$etag":"W\/\"C0YCR38_fip7I2A9Wh5UEkw.\"","entry":[{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"He was doin his shit before Logic though. I don't think either of them know \neach other. Wax is a lot older."},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:z13eg1lpnsbjffkvh23bczqysty3dld0f"},"yt$googlePlusUserId":{"$t":"108900457503123436988"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"CHSZNY4x6F6pWRJobUoFYQ"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/CHSZNY4x6F6pWRJobUoFYQ"},"name":{"$t":"Aaron Tucci"}}],"title":{"$t":"He was doin his ..."},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-11-20T17:14:52.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"DUENQ347eCp7I2A9Wh5XGUs.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/z13eg1lpnsbjffkvh23bczqysty3dld0f?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-11-20T17:14:52.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UCCHSZNY4x6F6pWRJobUoFYQ"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"This will play at my funeral"},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:z12qdzqpvtzzgb3wn04cefsy5yfbtpwgfr40k"},"yt$googlePlusUserId":{"$t":"114722569313545191091"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"SSYvgm-__QWJ-QBn7WBCOA"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/EvincentDavis73"},"name":{"$t":"EvincentDavis73"}}],"title":{"$t":"This will play at ..."},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-11-25T22:03:55.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"DUcHRH47eCp7I2A9Wh5WFEw.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/z12qdzqpvtzzgb3wn04cefsy5yfbtpwgfr40k?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-11-25T22:03:55.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UCSSYvgm-__QWJ-QBn7WBCOA"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"Damn Wax, will always be chill"},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:ENZPbF_dkcQPL32E3PWUkDO2TriUzzdwwutHskE4KyI"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"HvHwTN1oQo8ReLJizlGeTA"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/HvHwTN1oQo8ReLJizlGeTA"},"name":{"$t":"Mark Henry Salvador"}}],"title":{"$t":"Damn Wax, will ..."},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-10-22T17:57:38.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"DkEBSX47eCp7I2A9Wh5RFEs.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/ENZPbF_dkcQPL32E3PWUkDO2TriUzzdwwutHskE4KyI?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-10-22T17:57:38.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UCHvHwTN1oQo8ReLJizlGeTA"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"Chill song"},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:ENZPbF_dkcS4GpS8ZITWuVUsUYNyrGQGWajSGKIXO38"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"hXnILfiYMX0Li4Ok99RDVQ"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/hXnILfiYMX0Li4Ok99RDVQ"},"name":{"$t":"thedudesons55xD"}}],"title":{"$t":"Chill song"},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-10-18T17:38:09.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"DU8MSH47eCp7I2A9Wh5REUw.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/ENZPbF_dkcS4GpS8ZITWuVUsUYNyrGQGWajSGKIXO38?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-10-18T17:38:09.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UChXnILfiYMX0Li4Ok99RDVQ"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"Jammed to this song at the Lancaster show, just fuckin great."},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:ENZPbF_dkcRbJyAUdl6-zrqjvoZsxzicrhGx2ZovIaI"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"-EhhQyun4YBw_LvMZXwXRg"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/-EhhQyun4YBw_LvMZXwXRg"},"name":{"$t":"RadiationDubstep"}}],"title":{"$t":"Jammed to this song ..."},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-10-17T19:32:12.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"AkQHQ347eCp7I2A9Wh5REE4.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/ENZPbF_dkcRbJyAUdl6-zrqjvoZsxzicrhGx2ZovIaI?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-10-17T19:32:12.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UC-EhhQyun4YBw_LvMZXwXRg"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"he sounds like logic"},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:ENZPbF_dkcSsgrj7dLTiPt_IbMf0WCv3vPaBnNorDEE"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"IVTqw7FaRUFdTgK6-XCJsg"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/IVTqw7FaRUFdTgK6-XCJsg"},"name":{"$t":"Johnny Trikhin"}}],"title":{"$t":"he sounds like logic"},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-10-17T03:06:36.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"A0YNR347eCp7I2A9Wh5SGUo.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns?v=2","rel":"related"},{"type":"text\/html","href":"http:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=AaWp8YZi1Ns","rel":"alternate"},{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/videos\/AaWp8YZi1Ns\/comments\/ENZPbF_dkcSsgrj7dLTiPt_IbMf0WCv3vPaBnNorDEE?v=2","rel":"self"}],"published":{"$t":"2013-10-17T03:06:36.000Z"},"yt$channelId":{"$t":"UCIVTqw7FaRUFdTgK6-XCJsg"},"yt$replyCount":{"$t":0}},{"yt$videoid":{"$t":"AaWp8YZi1Ns"},"content":{"$t":"Hats off to Wax AND EOM, people don't give E enough credit"},"id":{"$t":"tag:youtube.com,2008:video:AaWp8YZi1Ns:comment:ENZPbF_dkcT6kdus1Qc0wE8XcjPxgFjuZ26nZfV8EQM"},"author":[{"yt$userId":{"$t":"tmYlMT3VSyjLOt6KXeTJjg"},"uri":{"$t":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/feeds\/api\/users\/tmYlMT3VSyjLOt6KXeTJjg"},"name":{"$t":"PZMCWEequalsMC3"}}],"title":{"$t":"Hats off to Wax AND ..."},"category":[{"scheme":"http:\/\/schemas.google.com\/g\/2005#kind","term":"http:\/\/gdata.youtube.com\/schemas\/2007#comment"}],"updated":{"$t":"2013-10-08T04:31:11.000Z"},"gd$etag":"W\/\"DEEDQH47eCp7I2A9Wh5SEk0.\"","link":[{"type":"application\/atom+xml","href":"http:\/\/gdata.you...
```

[image]

Comment: Can you share the Full JSON Response? I can definitely help you figure this out but your going to have to go to http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and format your FULL JSON Response for me. The one you provided is invalid

Comment: Thank you! http://pastebin.com/JUnjbSm4

Comment: Awesome. Thanks Can you also post your `CommentsLibrary` Class i need to see how your assigning the values to your `TextView`s

Comment: Is there anything else you might need?

Comment: unrelated comment : I assume StreamUtilis is a class of yours. There is a class integrated in android that is called EntityUtils and that contains a toString(Entity) which does pretty much the same as your convertToString (and you can give it a charset, too)

Comment: I don't think so. Did you give my Answer a try?

Comment: Finally Fixed your issue. copy and past the doInBackground Method i submitted under **Update 3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line, You are not updated the right list of information

```
list.add(new CommentsLibrary(name, content, published));
```

**UPDATE**

You are instantiating the wrong type of object. Your `ArrayList` expects `Comments` so make this change below to instantiate a `Comments` Object.

```
comments.add(new CommentsLibrary(name, content, published));
```

to

```
comments.add(new Comments(name, content, published));
```

or if the `CommentsLibrary` is actually what you want then Change your ArrayList and adapter to accept this Type.

Let me know if this is the problem. It looks to me like `list` is not what you want to add items to. And you want to add them to the comments ArrayList

And also when initializeing your adapter use the `comments` Arraylist As well

```
CustomAdapter cus = new CustomAdapter(Player.this, comments);
```

**Update 2**

I believe you are never calling `setName(name);` `setContent(content);` `setPublished(published);`
Make sure you are actually Calling these in your constructor in `CommentsLibrary.java`

**Update 3**

Besides actually Having some problems with your layouts and your classes that we had fixed yesterday you have been `parsing` the `JSON` data wrong. I fixed the parsing logic for you and you can probably copy and paste this code into your `doInBackground()` Method.

That should be it. Just replace your method with this one. And all should be well!
Good Luck.

CODE

```
 @Override
 protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

       DefaultHttpClient client = null;

       HttpGet getMethod = null;

       HttpResponse response = null;

       HttpEntity entity = null;

       URI requestUri = null;


       try {

           client       = new DefaultHttpClient();

           requestUri   = new URI("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/"
                                 + video_id
                                 + "/comments?v=2&alt=json&start-index=1&max-results=50&prettyprint=true");

           getMethod    = new HttpGet(requestUri);

           response     = client.execute(getMethod);

           if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){

               entity = response.getEntity();

               String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

               JSONObject json   = new JSONObject(jsonString);

               // Get the Feed From the JSON Response
               JSONObject feeds         = json.getJSONObject("feed");
               JSONArray entryArray     = feeds.getJSONArray("entry");

               for(int i = 0; i < entryArray.length(); i++){

                   // Get the entry at index 0
                   JSONObject entry = entryArray.getJSONObject(i);

                   // Get the Published data
                   JSONObject publishedObject = entry.getJSONObject("published");
                   published = publishedObject.getString("$t");


                   // Get the Content of the Comment
                   JSONObject contentObject = entry.getJSONObject("content");
                   content = contentObject.getString($t);

                   // Get the Author of the content
                   JSONArray commentNames = entry.getJSONArray("author");
                   for(int j = 0; j < commentNames.length(); j++){

                       // Get the Author Object at the first index
                       JSONObject singleAuthor = commentNames.getJSONObject(j);
                       JSONObject authorName = singleAuthor.getJSONObject("name");

                       name = authorName.getString("$t");
                   }

                   comments.add(new CommentsLibrary(name, content, published));

               }

           }
        }catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.d("ClientProtocolException", ""+ e);

        }catch(URISyntaxException e){

             Log.d("URISyntaxException",""+ e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("IOException",""+ e);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.d("JSONException",""+ e);
        }
            return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I almost have it... I'm getting one small error though: http://pastebin.com/5mxEkSYm

Comment: Read above. You can't create an `ArrayList<Comments>` and try to fill it with `CommentsLibrary` objects , type casting may work but I think you just have just confused your `CommentsLibrary` with `Comments`

Comment: Ok - I implemented it as suggested and I still get nothing in my textView : ( http://pastebin.com/Y8PA8TtX

Comment: Okay, I think were down to the last problem. You are calling `setAdapter` on your `listview` before your task executes. So when you get the response from the Handler then call `lv.setAdapter(cus);` Think that should solve it! To make this work. Make your `ListView` a member of your class and initialize it in OnCreate.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think I should add it after task.execute(); or onPostExecute? Also (sorry for asking so many questions) Isn't my listView already a memeber of my class and initialized in oncreate?  http://pastebin.com/1xcCGmz1

Comment: Do it from your onPostExecute(). So Call a new method like updateList(); inside this call and then have updateList() initialize and set the Adapter.

Comment: I just tried - and still nothing appears in my textViews : ( pastebin.com/N4ZCbV6f

Comment: Any ideas on what else I might do? I really appreciate your help... I'm behind on a deadline and this is the last part holding me up before I finish

Comment: Are you calling setName(name); setContent(content); setPublished(published); in your CommentsLibrary.java class?

Comment: you have only declared the Methods for the class. by calling this.name = name; your not setting the value. add setName(name); setContent(content); setPublished(published); to your constructor

Comment: Mind if we chat for a moment?

Comment: I would also remove the static modifiers for these methods and variables